# Django unable to bind uploaded file

Tags: python, django, csv, django-forms, django-templates

Clarification: I'm developing on top of the django admin module.

I implemented a csv model upload using a simple `FileField` form, and read the uploaded text file with a `TextIOWrapper` without any problems.

I am trying to add an intermediate screen warning the user of potential data loss. I'm basing it off the admin delete action confirmation screen. The problem I'm having is passing the in-memory uploaded file to the intermediate screen to access it upon user confirmation. I tried doing this with a bound form but the uploaded data seems to vanish.

I am using a very simple form:

```
class CsvImportForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField()
    overwrite = forms.BooleanField()
```

I have no problem when serving the `GET` view.

Now comes the funny part. When processing the same view for a `POST` request, I try to bind the form [as per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form), and pass it to the template builder:

```
def import_csv(self, request, form_url="", extra_context=None):
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CsvImportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        context.update({'form': form})
        ...
        return TemplateResponse(
            request,
            "admin/import_confirm.html",
            context
    )
```

The `import_csv` method is part of my `ModelAdmin` subclass, and gets called by overriding the `get_urls` method.

The template builds the form like so:

```html
<form action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    ...
    {{ form.csv_file }}
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Yes, I’m sure' %}">
    <a href="#" class="button cancel-link">{% translate "No, take me back" %}</a>
    ...
</form>
```

However, when loading this view, the builtin `ClearableFileInput` appears empty. I even tried loading the same template as the `GET` view but the same problem appears. Of particular note, the `BooleanField` gets bound correctly if I choose to put it.

During debugging, the file *does* exist in `request.FILES`, but it somehow dissapears after passing the view to the renderer.

What am I overlooking? Or is there a better way to pass the file?

Comment: Do you see any errors after `form.is_valid()`? You can see it with `form.errors`.

Comment: @NKSM `form.is_valid()` returns `True` after creating the bound form.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that for security reasons, it's not possible to serve the user a form with a bound file.

My solution was to use a javascript popup, so that way the content doesn't have to reload.